# UWP EF SQLite referencing to inherited types throws exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, uwp

We want to reference a inherited Control in Completion because one Control has a list of possible Completions and saves the selected Completion.
Our tables are

```
public class Completion
{
    public int CompletionId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public virtual Control Control { get; set; }
}
public class Control : BaseControl
{
    public int ControlId { get; set; }

    public virtual Completion Completion { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Completion> Completions { get; set; }
}
```

the migration of these tables works, but if we try to add a Completion to the database, we get the exception

> {"SQLite Error 1: 'foreign key mismatch - \"Completion\" referencing \"Control\"'"}

we add a Completion like this

`var completion = new Completion { Text = "completion1" };
 db.Completions.Add(completion);
 db.SaveChanges();`

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the error message, your question is about SQLite not EF.

The `public virtual Control Control { get; set; }` on your `Completion` class is getting treated as a foreign key to a Control table that you did not define.

My guess is you do not want save the Control reference into SQLite. So int this case, make SQLite ignore the column

```
[SQLite.Ignore]
public virtual Control Control { get; set; }
```

Comment: But we have a Control table definied (we have Control and Completion) and we want to save the Control in a Completion. One Control has a list of possible Completions and one specific Completions that is the selected one